# Formatting a hard disk previously formatted on Mac OS X with Windows

Tags: windows-7, formatting, mac-mini

I am trying to format a USB hard disk previously formatted with a Mac Mini on Windows, but it doesn't let me format it.

From the Microsoft Management Console, I was able to delete one partition, but I cannot format the hard disk, which is reported from Windows 7 to be a EFI disk (it doesn't report the file system, though).

How can I format it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have had this problem before. What happens is that the disk has a GUID Partition Table instead of being set up as a Master Boot Record. Windows seems to have serious problems getting things back to the way they should be. The easiest solution would be to hook it up to a Mac and use Disk Utility to repartition it, set it up as a Master Boot Record and format it as FAT. After that you can do whatever you want to it in Windows.

If you do not have access to a Mac to do this there is another solution that I know works for sure. If you have a Linux Live CD with GParted restart your computer and boot into it. If you do not have a Live CD you can download and burn the [GParted Live CD](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php). After you boot into the Linux environment you will be able to convert the drive to any filesystem and partition table you want.